# Responder Error with Shibboleth and Node.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js, saml, shibboleth

I have set up a shibboleth service provider on a server, 40.78.18.242. When I try to access http://40.78.18.242/secure/index.html , everything works as planned. I'm redirected to my identity provider and then, once I login, I am able to access resources in my secure directory.

I'm trying to secure a node.js application with this same Shibboleth service provider setup. I have looked into the passport-saml module, and I'm running the test project @ https://github.com/gbraad/passport-saml-example/ with the following changes made to the config file:

[image: code set up]

But whenever I get redirected to the login page at the IdP, the response gives me this error:

[image: after I'm redirected]

I have a feeling I'm not understanding the requirements for passport-js correctly, as this error message only had 1-2 results in google.

Am I entering an incorrect entry **point** or **issuer**? Or **can you gather what those would be, given my shibboleth2.xml file**?

A snippet of my shibboleth file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
    xmlns:conf="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
    xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
    logger="/etc/shibboleth/syslog.logger" clockSkew="180">

    <!-- The OutOfProcess section contains properties affecting the shibd daemon. -->
    <OutOfProcess logger="/etc/shibboleth/shibd.logger">
        <!--
        <Extensions>
            <Library path="odbc-store.so" fatal="true"/>
        </Extensions>
        -->
    </OutOfProcess>

    <InProcess logger="/etc/shibboleth/native.logger" />

    <UnixListener address="shibd.sock" />
    <!-- This set of components stores sessions and other persistent data in daemon memory. -->
    <StorageService type="Memory" id="mem" cleanupInterval="900"/>
    <SessionCache type="StorageService" StorageService="mem" cacheTimeout="3600" inprocTimeout="900" cleanupInterval="900"/>
    <ReplayCache StorageService="mem"/>
    <ArtifactMap artifactTTL="180"/>

    <!-- This set of components stores sessions and other persistent data in an ODBC database. -->
    <!--
    <StorageService type="ODBC" id="db" cleanupInterval="900">
        <ConnectionString>
        DRIVER=drivername;SERVER=dbserver;UID=shibboleth;PWD=password;DATABASE=shibboleth;APP=Shibboleth
        </ConnectionString>
    </StorageService>
    <SessionCache type="StorageService" StorageService="db" cacheTimeout="3600" inprocTimeout="900" cleanupInterval="900"/>
    <ReplayCache StorageService="db"/>
    <ArtifactMap StorageService="db" artifactTTL="180"/>
    -->

    <!-- To customize behavior, map hostnames and path components to applicationId and other settings. -->
    <RequestMapper type="Native">
        <RequestMap applicationId="default">
            <!--
            The example requires a session for documents in /secure on the containing host with http and
            https on the default ports. Note that the name and port in the <Host> elements MUST match
            Apache's ServerName and Port directives or the IIS Site name in the <ISAPI> element
            below.
            -->

            <Host name="40.78.18.242"
                  applicationId="rename--my-application-name"
                  authType="shibboleth"
                  requireSession="true"
                  exportAssertion="false">
                <AccessControl>
                    <!-- IMPORTANT: You must replace this with your application's entitlement
                         when switching to production! -->
                    <Rule require="entitlement">urn:mace:usc.edu:gds:entitlement:stmn7vt3</Rule>
                </AccessControl>
             </Host>

            <!-- Examples of a second vhost mapped to a different applicationId. -->
            <!--
            <Host name="admin.example.org" applicationId="admin" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
            or
            <Host name="admin.example.org">
                <Path name="applicationPath" applicationId="admin" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" exportAssertion="false">
                    <AccessControl>
                        <Rule require="entitlement">urn:mace:usc.edu:gds:entitlement:yourentitlementvaluehere</Rule>
                    </AccessControl>
                </Path>
            </Host>
            -->
        </RequestMap>
    </RequestMapper>

<!--
    The ApplicationDefaults element is where most of Shibboleth's SAML bits are defined.
    Resource requests are mapped by the RequestMapper to an applicationId that
    points into to this section.

    These are the default global settings for all applications.
    !DO NOT CHANGE THIS SECTION!  Application-specific settings are set in the
    <ApplicationOverride> section.
    -->
    <ApplicationDefaults id="default" policyId="default"
        entityID="https://www.usc.edu/do-not-use"
        homeURL="https://www.usc.edu/"
        REMOTE_USER="eppn persistent-id targeted-id"
        signing="true" encryption="false"
        >

        <!--
        Controls session lifetimes, address checks, cookie handling, and the protocol handlers.
        You MUST supply an effectively unique handlerURL value for each of your applications.
        The value can be a relative path, a URL with no hostname (https:///path) or a full URL.
        The system can compute a relative value based on the virtual host. Using handlerSSL="true"
        will force the protocol to be https. You should also add a cookieProps setting of "; path=/; secure; HttpOnly"
        in that case. Note that while we default checkAddress to "false", this has a negative
        impact on the security of the SP. Stealing cookies/sessions is much easier with this disabled.
        -->
        <Sessions lifetime="7200" timeout="3600" checkAddress="false" consistentAddress="true"
            handlerURL="/Shibboleth.sso" handlerSSL="true"
            exportLocation="http://localhost/Shibboleth.sso/GetAssertion"
            cookieProps="; path=/; secure; HttpOnly"
            idpHistory="true" idpHistoryDays="7">

            <!--
            SessionInitiators handle session requests and relay them to a Discovery page,
            or to an IdP if possible. Automatic session setup will use the default or first
            element (or requireSessionWith can specify a specific id to use).
            -->

            <!-- Default example directs to a specific IdP's SSO service (favoring SAML 2 over Shib 1). -->

            <SessionInitiator type="Chaining" Location="/Login" isDefault="true" id="Intranet"
                    relayState="cookie" entityID="https://shibboleth-test.usc.edu/shibboleth-idp"
                    acsByIndex="false">
                <SessionInitiator type="SAML2" acsIndex="1" template="bindingTemplate.html"/>
                <SessionInitiator type="Shib1" acsIndex="5"/>
            </SessionInitiator>


            <!-- An example using an old-style WAYF, which means Shib 1 only unless an entityID is provided. -->
            <SessionInitiator type="Chaining" Location="/WAYF/shibboleth.usc.edu" id="usc" relayState="cookie">
                <SessionInitiator type="SAML2" acsIndex="1" template="bindingTemplate.html"/>
                <SessionInitiator type="Shib1" acsIndex="5"/>
                <SessionInitiator type="WAYF" acsIndex="5" URL="https://shibboleth-test.usc.edu/idp/profile/Shibboleth/SSO"/>
            </SessionInitiator>


            <!--
            md:AssertionConsumerService locations handle specific SSO protocol bindings,
            such as SAML 2.0 POST or SAML 1.1 Artifact. The isDefault and index attributes
            are used when sessions are initiated to determine how to tell the IdP where and
            how to return the response.
            -->
            <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/POST" index="1"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
            <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/POST-SimpleSign" index="2"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST-SimpleSign"/>
            <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/Artifact" index="3"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"/>
            <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML2/ECP" index="4"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:PAOS"/>
            <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML/POST" index="5"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post"/>
            <md:AssertionConsumerService Location="/SAML/Artifact" index="6"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01"/>

            <!-- LogoutInitiators enable SP-initiated local or global/single logout of sessions. -->
            <LogoutInitiator type="Chaining" Location="/Logout" relayState="cookie" >
<!--                <LogoutInitiator type="SAML2" template="bindingTemplate.html"/>  -->
                <LogoutInitiator type="Local" />
            </LogoutInitiator>

            <!-- md:SingleLogoutService locations handle single logout (SLO) protocol messages. -->
            <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/SOAP"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"/>
            <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/Redirect" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
            <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/POST" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
            <md:SingleLogoutService Location="/SLO/Artifact" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"/>

            <!-- md:ManageNameIDService locations handle NameID management (NIM) protocol messages. -->
            <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/SOAP"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"/>
            <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/Redirect" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"/>
            <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/POST" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
            <md:ManageNameIDService Location="/NIM/Artifact" conf:template="bindingTemplate.html"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"/>

            <!--
            md:ArtifactResolutionService locations resolve artifacts issued when using the
            SAML 2.0 HTTP-Artifact binding on outgoing messages, generally uses SOAP.
            -->
            <md:ArtifactResolutionService Location="/Artifact/SOAP" index="1"
                Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP"/>

            <!-- Extension service that generates "approximate" metadata based on SP configuration. -->
            <Handler type="MetadataGenerator" Location="/Metadata" signing="false"/>

            <!-- Status reporting service. -->
            <Handler type="Status" Location="/Status" acl="127.0.0.1"/>

            <!-- Session diagnostic service. -->
            <Handler type="Session" Location="/Session" showAttributeValues="true" />

        </Sessions>

        <!--
        You should customize these pages! You can add attributes with values that can be plugged
        into your templates. You can remove the access attribute to cause the module to return a
        standard 403 Forbidden error code if authorization fails, and then customize that condition
        using your web server.
        -->
        <Errors session="/etc/shibboleth/sessionError.html"
            metadata="/etc/shibboleth/metadataError.html"
            access="/etc/shibboleth/accessError.html"
            ssl="/etc/shibboleth/sslError.html"
            localLogout="/etc/shibboleth/localLogout.html"
            globalLogout="/etc/shibboleth/globalLogout.html"
            supportContact="peter.kaminski09@gmail.com"
            logoLocation="/shibboleth-sp/logo.jpg"
            styleSheet="/shibboleth-sp/main.css"/>

        <MetadataProvider type="XML"
                          url="https://shibboleth.usc.edu/USC-metadata.xml"
                          backingFilePath="USC-metadata.xml"
                          reloadInterval="86400" />

        <!-- Chain the two built-in trust engines together. -->
        <TrustEngine type="Chaining">
            <TrustEngine type="ExplicitKey"/>
            <TrustEngine type="PKIX"/>
        </TrustEngine>

        <!-- Map to extract attributes from SAML assertions. -->
        <AttributeExtractor type="XML" path="/etc/shibboleth/attribute-map.xml"/>

        <!-- Use a SAML query if no attributes are supplied during SSO. -->
        <AttributeResolver type="Query"/>

        <!-- Default filtering policy for recognized attributes, lets other data pass. -->
        <AttributeFilter type="XML" path="/etc/shibboleth/attribute-policy.xml"/>

        <!-- Simple file-based resolver for using a single keypair. -->
        <CredentialResolver type="File"
                            key="/etc/shibboleth/sp-key.pem"
                            certificate="/etc/shibboleth/sp-cert.pem"/>

        <!-- *************************************** -->
        <!-- Custom application settings begin here. -->
        <!-- *************************************** -->

        <!--
            In the ApplicationOverride section:
                id - should match the name you use in the RequestMapper
                     Rename this value to the name of your application.
                     If you have multiple applications, they will have
                     multiple ApplicationOverride sections with different id=""

                entityID - should be set for you automatically by the generator
                           please follow the instructions in detail from the website
                           regarding your entityID.  This is an overall identifer
                           for your application and should not be linked to a
                           specific box, but should be a link into the space of
                           your overall departmental website.  It does not have
                           to resolve to anything, but may one day be used to
                           house a configuration file.

                homeURL - this value will vary by machine.  This is where shibboleth
                          will return when it can do nothing further with a request.

                REMOTE_USER - If you would like the standard REMOTE_USER definition
                              in the environment of your application, set this value.
                              For example, if you receive uscNetID, you would set:
                              REMOTE_USER="ShibuscNetID"
                              (That is the identifier defined in attribute-map.xml)

        -->

        <ApplicationOverride id="rename--my-application-name"
                             entityID="https://www.trojantime.usc.edu/timesheethistorial/shibboleth-sp"
                             homeURL="http://40.78.18.242/"
                             REMOTE_USER="ShibuscNetID" />



    </ApplicationDefaults>

    <!-- Policies that determine how to process and authenticate runtime messages. -->
    <SecurityPolicyProvider type="XML" validate="true" path="security-policy.xml"/>

</SPConfig>
```

Comment: It sounds like the service provider is asking for a SAML NameID format that your Identity Provider is not releasing to you. You either need to change the NameID format you are asking for your get your identity provider to release the required NameID format.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. I'm guessing that the Passport-js package is trying to access something that I'm not aware of, or haven't had to access during my initial set up. I'll look into it. Thank you

Comment: @PeterKaminski did you get this resolved? If so it would be great if you could leave a few details to help others in the same situation

Comment: It's been so long, I can't remember if I did get it resolved.

Comment: Had similar issue using ADFS which fixed by setting value for identifierFormat when configuring passport-saml as shown https://github.com/Kiarashz/passport-saml-example/blob/master/config/config.js#L18

Answer (score 0):

According to `passport-saml` [docs](https://github.com/node-saml/passport-saml#config-parameter-details), the default **NameID Format** is `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress`, quoting:

> `identifierFormat`: optional name identifier format to request from identity provider (default: `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress`)

So your IDP is not supported the requested NameID Format. You need either to change the SP passport settings to a NameID Format IDP supports, or request to IDP admin (if you don't have direct access to it) to accept `emailAddress`.